# Subviews with own controllers in iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios

What do you think would be the best approach for the following situation:
My iPhone app needs to be able to present data in 2 ways : list view ( with UITableView ) and a map view. I want user to be able to switch between them tapping one of two buttons. 
Initially I thought about nesting ListViewController and MapViewController inside of the root view controller and adding their views as subviews of root view controller's view. 
Something like that ( inside of the root view controller's viewDidLoad method):

```
[self addChildViewController:self.listController];
[self addChildViewController:self.mapController];
[self.view addSubview:self.listController.view];
[self.view addSubview:self.mapController.view];
```

Do you think that this is the most effective way of doing it or are there any better solutions considering the fact that it has to work on iOS5 and higher?

Answer (score 0):

There can be two ways :

1. By taking views : In this apporach, add two views (such as mapview and listview) in RootViewController's view.
2. by taking view controllers: In this appraoch, add two viewcontrollers (such as MapViewController and ListViewController) in RootViewController's view.

Memory wise, it is better to use first approach. But functionally, if you want to perform many operations on individual child controllers, then use second approach.